UV Projection from view, how can i flatten only the UV to create a skinnable UV layout template for Photoshop?
I am trying to create a template for a truck to skin in photoshop. My workflow is as shown/explained below.
I use orthographic view to "project from view" to create the left and right sides of the truck, to then export the UV layout for photoshop. Since there are some curved edges, it does not completely look flat in the UV, and if I were to skin the rounded parts, they would of course come out as stretched. Is there an easy fix for it?
Here is the example. 
Result with the current UV layout and with a decal applied, which is shown stretched 
https://we.tl/t-xY2H3mXJlO This is the model i am working with

There is no need to delete the old question and post exactly the same again. Martynas told you, you have to UV unwrap the model, you said that would be no option because you need the layout in Photoshop to create decals. I'm not sure you understand what UV unwrapping does...? Because that's what people usually do, unwrap the UVs so that they can create textures in software like Photohop etc. which they want to be placed on specific parts of the mesh... but automatic unwrapping is not always perfect, that's why there are tons of tutorials on how to achieve best results, special tricks etc.

@GordonBrinkmann I know well enough what "UV unwrapping" does, but with all due respect, it was a fairly generalized answer, wasn't it? I'm just wondering how I should approach it, so coming up with a general answer is an answer by stating the obvious? That was not my question, and I don't think that is the intention of the site either. Now the answer for me was not the problem, just to be clear, "because you make that judgment yourself." I simply wanted to recreate my post. With an improved explanation, I didn't have any bad intentions. If it came across that way, my apologies

Since you know what UV unwrapping is, you know how complex it can be and there is no simple solution for everything. There are so many ways how you can try to get the most "unstretched" result, from trying with _Follow Active Quads" to whatever... manually creating the UVs etc. In your case, since you want the front part in a different angle as the side, why do you select all and the Project from View? Select for example the side part first, unwrap it, then the front part and try to manually stitch them together in the UV Editor... And for recreating the post: just edit it like you did now.

M0L0T0V, you are talking about something being "obvious"... Well, sure it is obvious to me, yes, but many answers are obvious to me since I know them and it's impossible for me to know if they are obvious to you or anybody asking the questions. How should I know? It wasn't an answer, by the way. It was a comment. So there was no need to delete it, you could have edited it and clarified just as well. Nothing wrong with deleting it and writing a new one, just no need for it.

Martynas Žiemys, Thank you for clarifying.

Unfortunately, this question has a very simple definitive answer: No, not only there is no easy way, there is no way at all to do what you want.
Nothing to do with Blender, it's just how geometry works. You cannot flatten any 3d surface without stretching. Some are possible to flatten without stretching:

And some are not:

It's not a software, skill or workflow limitation it is a physical one.
